# no sound on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound

I have just installed the latest version and I have no sound. I tried all solutions I could find on the web, including drivers from the sound dev repository, running alsamixer, etc, but nothing helps. Would someone please help? I am new to ubuntu, I have no idea where to look. Microphone works, and it seems to recognize my laptop's on-board sound.

```
marilyn2
    description: Notebook
    product: Satellite P105 ()
    vendor: TOSHIBA
    version: PSPA0U-018006
    serial: 46110668W
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp-1.4 smp
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=oem-specific chassis=notebook cpus=2 frontpanel_password=unknown keyboard_password=unknown power-on_password=disabled uuid=A03195E0-A4B9-DA11-9504-001636272B4C
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Satellite P105
       vendor: TOSHIBA
       physical id: 0
       version: Not Applicable
       serial: 1234567890
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: TOSHIBA
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.70
          date: 03/16/2006
          size: 91KiB
          capacity: 960KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing escd cdboot acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2300  @ 1.66GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.14.8
          serial: 0000-06E8-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: U2E1
          size: 1GHz
          capacity: 1GHz
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 166MHz
          capabilities: boot fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor vmx est tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm cpufreq
          configuration: id=1
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 16KiB
             capacity: 16KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capabilities: burst external write-back
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 1.1
             width: 32 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 1.2
             width: 32 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: c
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
          capacity: 3GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous
             physical id: 0
             slot: M1
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous
             physical id: 1
             slot: M2
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
     *-cpu:1
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@1
          version: 6.14.8
          serial: 0000-06E8-0000-0000-0000-0000
          size: 1GHz
          capacity: 1GHz
          capabilities: vmx ht cpufreq
          configuration: id=1
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 1.1
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 1.2
             capabilities: logical
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:b0080000-b00fffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:b0040000-b007ffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:b0100000-b017ffff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:b0000000-b0003fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:80a00000-80bfffff ioport:80c00000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:80500000-807fffff ioport:80800000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:13:02:3d:ca:e2
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=3.2.0-29-generic-pae firmware=15.32.2.9 ip=192.168.254.45 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
                resources: irq:43 memory:80500000-80500fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:80100000-802fffff ioport:80300000(size=2097152)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 ioport:1820(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:1840(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 ioport:1860(size=32)
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:16 ioport:1880(size=32)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:b0004000-b00043ff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: e2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:b0300000-b03fffff ioport:84000000(size=67108864)
           *-pcmcia
                description: CardBus bridge
                product: PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
                vendor: Texas Instruments
                physical id: 4
                bus info: pci@0000:0a:04.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pcmcia bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=yenta_cardbus latency=176 maxlatency=5 mingnt=192
                resources: irq:17 memory:b0304000-b0304fff ioport:2800(size=256) ioport:2400(size=256) memory:84000000-87ffffff memory:88000000-8bffffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: PCIxx12 OHCI Compliant IEEE 1394 Host Controller
                vendor: Texas Instruments
                physical id: 4.1
                bus info: pci@0000:0a:04.1
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=3
                resources: irq:17 memory:b0305000-b03057ff memory:b0300000-b0303fff
           *-storage
                description: Mass storage controller
                product: 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
                vendor: Texas Instruments
                physical id: 4.2
                bus info: pci@0000:0a:04.2
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=tifm_7xx1 latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=7
                resources: irq:17 memory:b0306000-b0306fff
           *-generic
                description: SD Host controller
                product: PCIxx12 SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
                vendor: Texas Instruments
                physical id: 4.3
                bus info: pci@0000:0a:04.3
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=64 maxlatency=4 mingnt=7
                resources: irq:17 memory:b0305800-b03058ff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: PRO/100 VE Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 8
                bus info: pci@0000:0a:08.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:16:36:27:2b:4c
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e100 driverversion=3.5.24-k2-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=64 link=no maxlatency=56 mingnt=8 multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:20 memory:b0307000-b0307fff ioport:2000(size=64)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ide pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:18b0(size=16)
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: FUJITSU MHV2160B
                vendor: Fujitsu
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 0000
                serial: NU09T6325RJY
                size: 149GiB (160GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=486d5b3c
              *-volume:0
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: 2e87a6f3-84dc-3544-8db8-080f29946e53
                   size: 63GiB
                   capacity: 63GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2009-09-02 21:29:45 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
              *-volume:1
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   size: 85GiB
                   capacity: 85GiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume:0
                      description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      capacity: 2037MiB
                      capabilities: nofs
                 *-logicalvolume:1
                      description: Linux filesystem partition
                      physical id: 6
                      logical name: /dev/sda6
                      logical name: /
                      capacity: 83GiB
                      configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered state=mounted
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD-RAM writer
                product: DVDRAM GMA-4082N
                vendor: HL-DT-ST
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/cdrw
                logical name: /dev/dvd
                logical name: /dev/dvdrw
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: HV02
                capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:18c0(size=32)
  *-remoteaccess UNCLAIMED
       vendor: Intel
       physical id: 1
       capabilities: inbound
```

Comment: more info on your sound card, laptop and desktop environment (Unity, KDE, Xfce) needed

Comment: please tell me what commands I need to run and I will post the output

Comment: `sudo lshw | less` and specify the Desktop Environment too

Comment: I have edited my question. thanks! what is the Desktop Environment? (yes I know the question sounds stupid) although I think it is unity. whatever comes with the OS by default.

Comment: it is not stupid: every ubuntu user will bump into the issue: there are more ubuntus that one usually knows when starting using ubuntu. after founding that i put the lesson on this blog: http://cipricuslinux.blogspot.com/p/what-is-ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-lubuntu.html just for my own use, please excuse the self-promoting aspect. in fact the answer to a question like yours might be different according to the DE you have

Comment: I am using Unity. the DE that comes with ubuntu 12.04 by default.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4646/discussion-between-cipricus-and-akonsu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: for me upgrading my laptop's (Toshiba Satellite with Conexant audio) BIOS helped.  For more information on how to update BIOS under Ubuntu, take a look at [HOWTO: Flash BIOS, The Ubuntu Way](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=318789)

Answer (score 0):

In the "Sound settings" Dialogue be sure you have selected "Analog Output (Built in Audio)" instead of anything else.

Install "gnome alsa mixer" and "pulse audio control" and set the values to max.

Answer (score 0):

In the "Sound settings" Dialogue be sure you have selected "Analog Output (Built in Audio)" instead of anything else.__ copied from your answer.
For my case I only have Dummy output and nothing else _ no testing sound / no input and everything silence but the videos is perfect.